# Equivalence of p-vectors and skew-symmetric tensors

Tags: linear-algebra, differential-forms, multilinear-algebra, exterior-algebra

It is said (e.g. Lovelock and Rund) that p-vectors are equivalent to skew-symmetric tensors. However, a skew-symmetric form, such as $A_{ijk}$, is a **specific** form on $\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n$,
while an exterior algebra $$\bigwedge\nolimits^3\mathbb{R}^n$$
only corresponds to a specific form only **after** a functional a chosen on it. How do you reconcile the two?

In particular, how do you introduce an inner product on skew-symmetric tensors that corresponds to the usual definition on exterior algebras (determinant of the matrix of pairwise inner products of the elements in the p-blade).

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. "An exterior algebra" is not itself a form, but the *elements* of ${\bigwedge}V^*$ can be interpreted as forms. A skew symmetric form $(\mathbb R^n)^k \to \mathbb R$ corresponds uniquely to a form ${\bigwedge^k}\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ via the universal property of the exterior power. We can then put a canonical pairing on the exterior algebra ${\bigwedge}(\mathbb R^n)^*\times{\bigwedge}\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ which gives us $({\bigwedge}\mathbb R^n)^* \cong {\bigwedge}(\mathbb R^n)^*$.

Comment: Are you asking how to reconcile the tensor algebra pairing $T(V^*)\times T(V) \to \mathbb R$ with the exterior algebra pairing ${\bigwedge}V^*\times{\bigwedge}V\to\mathbb R$?

Comment: Yes, the elements of $\wedge V^*$ correspond uniquely to skew symmetric forms, but not the elements of $\wedge V$ themselves. If that's correct, then that's it. But then how do you define an inner product of skew symmetric forms that corresponds to the dot product on $\wedge V$?

Comment: if you have an (pseudo)inner product on $V$, then you can induce one on the exterior powers $\bigwedge^kV$ by $\langle v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_k,w_1\wedge\cdots\wedge w_k\rangle:=\det(\langle v_i,w_j\rangle)$. Ok more precisely, you first consider this as a bilinear mapping $V^k\times V^k\to\Bbb{R}$, and check that it is alternating in each $V^k$ factor, so that by the universal property, it descends to a unique bilinear map $\bigwedge^k(V)\times\bigwedge^k(V)\to\Bbb{R}$ whose action on the pure $k$-vectors is as above. Checking non-degeneracy (or positive-definiteness) is routine.

Comment: If you have it on $V$, you can then also induce it on $V^*$ and $\bigwedge^k(V^*)\cong (\bigwedge^kV)^*$ as usual.

Comment: You really need to revise your second (very long) sentence. You are confusing a vector space with elements of that vector space. Other than that, I think Nicholas and peek-a-boo have dealt with your issue. One can speak of a $p$-vector (an element of $\Lambda^p V$) just as one speaks of $p$-covectors (elements of $\Lambda^p V^*$).

Comment: On Page 7, Flanders states: "It can be shown that [the universal] property provides an axiomatic characterization of $$\bigwedge\nolimits^n L$$". Would one of the experts mind giving a (detailed, if possible) outline of that statement.